# how to connect mobile devices to Google cloud virtual instances?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I have created Virtual Machine instance, having ubuntu 17.04 with 500GB disk space.

I want to connect my mobile device to that virtual environment.
But im unable to do so.
Is there any way to do it?[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCxpy.jpg)

Comment: Have you researched adb over SSH?

Comment: @MorrisonChang will you help me with it?

Comment: I have the same problem how did you connect your phone to google cloud virtual machine